# SQL Query Count Since Start of Quarter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, window-functions, rolling-computation

I am trying to determine the best way to query a dataset to only count an individual once since the quarter began. Here is the dataset:

```
Year     |    Qtr    |    Week    |    Name
2021          1           1            John Smith
2021          1           3            John Smith
2021          2           14           John Smith
2021          1           1            Julie Johnson
2021          1           2            Julie Johnson
2021          1           3            John Jacobs
```

I need to be able to return a dataset that tells me the number of unique individuals by week, as well as the number of unique individuals quarter-to-date:

Result Set:

```
Year     |    Qtr    |    Week    |    Week Count    |    Rolling QTR Count
2021          1           1            2                  2   
2021          1           2            1                  2
2021          1           3            2                  3
2021          2           14           1                  1
```

I have tried using a window function to count, but I cannot figure out how to only count someone in a rolling time frame.

Comment: Which dbms you are using?

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Comment: What is a rolling quarter? You also said quarter to date. To me these are different things - rolling quarter is either "past 90 days, per day" or "since same date 3 months ago, per day" (and watch out, because that jumps at month ends eg Feb 28 goes back to Nov 28 but Mar 1 then skips Nov 29&30) but qtd is "since the start of the quarter, per day" which is a varying length window up to 92 days long

Answer (score 1):

Just add in a flag for the first week when the name appears in each quarter, and use that flag for the quarter column:

```
select year, qtr, week, count(*) as week_count,
       sum(sum(case when seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end)) over
           (partition by year, qtr order by week) as quarter_count
from (select d.*,
             row_number() over (partition by year, qtr, name order by week) as seqnum
      from dataset d
     ) d;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here goes a solution for your problem (Though I will try to optimize this if I could):

**Schema:**

> ```
> create table mytable(Year int, Qtr int,Week int, Name varchar(50));
> insert into mytable values(2021,1,1,            'John Smith');
> insert into mytable values(2021,1,3 ,           'John Smith');
> insert into mytable values(2021,2,14 ,          'John Smith');
> insert into mytable values(2021,1,1   ,         'Julie Johnson');
> insert into mytable values(2021,1,2    ,        'Julie Johnson');
> insert into mytable values(2021,1,3     ,       'John Jacobs');
> ```

**Query:**

> ```
> with RollingQtyCount as (
> select   m.year,m.qtr,m.week,count(name) over (partition by m.year,m.qtr,m.week) weekcount,
> count(t.distinct_names)over(partition by m.year,m.qtr order by m.week rows between unbounded preceding and current row) [Rolling QTR Count]from mytable m
>
> left join 
> (
>      select year,qtr,week, name distinct_names from mytable m where 
> not exists (select name from mytable mt where m.name = mt.name and m.year = mt.year and m.qtr = mt.qtr and m.week > mt.week)
>
> ) t on m.year=t.year and m.qtr=t.qtr and m.week=t.week and m.name=t.distinct_names 
> )
> select year,qtr,week ,max(weekcount)weekcount,max([Rolling QTR Count]) [Rolling QTR Count] from RollingQtyCount
> group by year,qtr,week
> GO
> ```

> | year | qtr | week | weekcount | Rolling QTR Count |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2021 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
> | 2021 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
> | 2021 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 3 |
> | 2021 | 2 | 14 | 1 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7ae64f8e883a5151068db07b95e2f4da)*